# Set %1 to variable in batch script

Tags: windows, command-line-arguments

I'm trying to write a batch script with variable number of arguments.  I'm using SHIFT in a loop to process each argument.  However, it seems I'm not able to assign the value of %1 to a variable within the script.  Here's my script:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
CLS
:loop
IF [%1] NEQ [] (
    echo Param 1: %1
    set curr_value=%1
    echo curr_value: %curr_value%
    shift 
    goto :loop
) ELSE (
     ECHO No more arguments
)
ENDLOCAL
```

and here's the result I'm getting:

```
Param 1: 1
curr_value: 3
Param 1: 2
curr_value: 1
Param 1: 3
curr_value: 2
Param 1: 4
curr_value: 3
No more arguments
```

I'm a bit confused why the number is just all scrambled, help!

Comment: As per the linked duplicate (and many other similar questions), `%curr_value%` is evaluated when you enter the block, i.e., before the `set` command.  You can solve this using delayed expansion, or you can use `goto` instead of `( )`.

Comment: Thanks Harry, that worked.